# How to disable Drag behaviour on ModalBottomSheet , android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

How to disable Drag behaviour on ModalBottomSheet , android compose , can't find nothing on google

tried draggable on modifier , nothing happened , then i tried to disable scroll behaviour but nothing happened again , please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the [workarounds](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242384339?pli=1).
But, It is better to use the sheetGesturesEnabled which is the property of BottomSheetScaffold and set it to false to get your desired result.

Comment: Big thank you !!! i've found on your link confirmStateChange = { false }, that helped in my case , you're my hero !

Comment: ModalBottomSheet and BottomSheetScaffold aren't the same thing though